# Joint positions to rotations

Tags: c++, rotation, transform, kinect

I have the following problem:
I need to transform skeleton joint positions, from Kinect, 
to joint rotation angles.

Comment: I hope you followed the[documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/guides.aspx). at least [the walkthrough](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/docs/SkeletalViewer_Walkthrough.pdf)

Comment: @D-Shan: The documentation/walkthrough you link to says nothing about what the OP wants to achieve, at least I cant find it. What page are you referring to?

Comment: it's about @PéterTörök 's"What have you tried so far? ".There is no any solution for the question there

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "rotation angle" is considering three pairs of joints ,
You can get the **relative** rotation angles but the absolute angles as follows. 
Say the joints are A,B and C

---

- You can define a triangle (traingle  ABC ).
- Then you can assign any value (say R ) as one of the three angles (ex: angle ABC = R ).
- Since you have the joint positions you can calculate the length of each 'edge' of the triangle using [distance formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm).
- Use [Cosine(Cos) Rule](http://www.math10.com/en/geometry/sin-cos-rule.html) to calculate the relative angles . 
  (which will be for example BAC = 0.2R ,  CAB = 3R etc)

As well as you can get the variation of a particular angle where distance between two joints are constant .( ex: consider Shoulder - Elbow and Elbow - Wrist ).
Initially angle ABC was R and Then 1.02R , Next 1.3R ..etc

Answer (score 1):

1. consider each joint as a vector.
2. axis angle between two vectors (one in current frame, come from kinect data. one in an initial pose. As the new SDK does not have an initial pose, you may need to set a virtual pose as the initial pose).
3. a rotation quaternion/matrix from axis angle

[More information on this page](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/index.htm).